# RegEx syntax for ImageMagick "identify" within bash shell

Tags: regex, grep, imagemagick, posix, posix-ere

I'm trying to run the ImageMagick identify command on a very large path of images where Identify returns the image dimensions of files that match a pattern. The pattern I'm trying to match is:

```
/jewelclub_[a-z0-9]{1,}_(small|medium|large|zoom)\.jpg/
```

When I try to execute the following two commands, the first succeeds and the second fails which seems like there must be something wrong with my RegExp:

```
(1): identify -format "%f %w %h %b \n" 'jewelclub_*\.jpg'
(2): identify -format "%f %w %h %b \n" 'jewelclub_[a-z0-9]{1,}_(small|medium|large|zoom)\.jpg'
```

Any advice on how to change my PCRE syntax in command #2 to a compatible RegEx flavor (BRE? ERE?)?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure `identify` accepts a regexp as file argument ?

how about this work-around, passing your regexp to `find` and then piping to `xargs`:

```
find -E . -regex "./jewelclub_[a-z0-9]{1,}_(small|medium|large|zoom)\.jpg" |\
xargs identify -format "%f %w %h %b \n"
```

Comment: `find -E` - which version of find is that? And why don't you use -exec, but xargs?

Comment: @userunknown you're right, I should've used `-exec` instead of piping to `xargs`. as for `find`, it's [what shipped](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) on this macbook (BSD derived).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `identify` works, But I can confirm that the regular expression that you used:

```
jewelclub_[a-z0-9]{1,}_(small|medium|large|zoom)\.jpg
```

is in correct ERE syntax.

To make it conform to the BRE standard, it's tricky, since BRE doesn't support the `(...|...|..)` syntax. 
If you needed to use a BRE, I would either go through each case with `identify` and then combine the results:

```
jewelclub_[a-z0-9]\{1,\}_small\.jpg
jewelclub_[a-z0-9]\{1,\}_medium\.jpg
jewelclub_[a-z0-9]\{1,\}_large\.jpg
jewelclub_[a-z0-9]\{1,\}_zoom\.jpg
```

Or I would make things simpler in the BRE:

```
jewelclub_[a-z0-9]\{1,\}_[smlz][[:alpha:]]\{3,5}\.jpg
```

See the [POSIX RegEx Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html).